# Why Parse.Cloud.run decodes returning object into object reference on success?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Take [Parse Javascript SDK 1.6.4](http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.js) for example,

from line 179:

```
_CoreManager2['default'].setCloudController({
  run: function run(name, data, options) {
    var RESTController = _CoreManager2['default'].getRESTController();

    var payload = (0, _encode2['default'])(data, true);

    var requestOptions = {};
    if (options.hasOwnProperty('useMasterKey')) {
      requestOptions.useMasterKey = options.useMasterKey;
    }
    if (options.hasOwnProperty('sessionToken')) {
      requestOptions.sessionToken = options.sessionToken;
    }

    var request = RESTController.request('POST', 'functions/' + name, payload, requestOptions);

    return request.then(function (res) {
      var decoded = (0, _decode2['default'])(res);
      if (decoded && decoded.hasOwnProperty('result')) {
        return _ParsePromise2['default'].as(decoded.result);
      }
      return _ParsePromise2['default'].error(new _ParseError2['default'](_ParseError2['default'].INVALID_JSON, 'The server returned an invalid response.'));
    })._thenRunCallbacks(options);
  }
});
```

The _decode2['default'] uses fromJSON for Parse Object from line 4144:

```
key: 'fromJSON',
value: function fromJSON(json) {
  if (!json.className) {
    throw new Error('Cannot create an object without a className');
  }
  var constructor = classMap[json.className];
  var o = constructor ? new constructor() : new ParseObject(json.className);
  var otherAttributes = {};
  for (var attr in json) {
    if (attr !== 'className' && attr !== '__type') {
      otherAttributes[attr] = json[attr];
    }
  }
  o._finishFetch(otherAttributes);
  if (json.objectId) {
    o._setExisted(true);
  }
  return o;
}
```

I passed a full Parse object in my cloud code run success callback, but this decoding behavior purges my returning Parse object into a object reference.

Why do we want to have this?

Is there a option to get full object instead of a reference?

What I want is to get an updated object to update my view on success.

Comment: I have the same problem. I get all data about objects from POST request, but in the Promise I get only objectId, className